# Run script as certain user -- depending on group membership

Tags: sudo, ssh-keys

I'm trying to run a script which calls another server through SSH (through Pub/Priv key). However depending on the user (or better said, his/her group membership) who runs the script through sudo, I'd want to invoke the script as a user who has the appropriate keys to access the server. This way users would be able access the remote server without them being able to see the key itself.

So, two users, with relevant groups:

- Joe:deploy_production
- John:deploy_acceptance

Is there a way that:

- if Joe runs the script through `sudo script` that the script is run under the `deploy_production` user
- if John runs the script through `sudo script` that the script is run under the `deploy_acceptance` user

Note: Only `script` should be whitelisted, as to stop users from sudo-cat'ing the key files.

Note: I'd rather not want to have to use the `-u <user>` option of sudo.

Rationale: this would provide me with easy access control, without having to put every user's ssh-key on servers on which they're allowed. So if I want to remove access to a server for a specific user, I'd remove him from one of the groups. If there is a better approach than my proposed solution using sudo, please advice.

Comment: You should be able to find the caller through `ps` and looking at the user of the parent pid of the current process?

Comment: I should've added that I can't alter  `script`  to do anything fancy, it should remain agnostic to this whole permission thing.